# Spring RestAPI with API key and Rate limiting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api-key

I just want to know certain things on Rest API to secure with api key and rate limiting on the rest api key for each api key.

What is the best solution for setting api key for a rest api and how to limit the access to the rest api for each api keys on a time periodic?.

Comment: See this [article](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way) it may help.

Comment: I just want a specific solution for this, any example project on this

Comment: Check this article http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs